# Trying to make multiple actions with different durations

Tags: animation, armature, timeline, actions

So I made two actions on a single armature (to which is attached an object), one for running and one for walking. Now, when I play one and adjust the playback time (timeline, I guess) thingy it plays nicely but the other one doesn't get to play all the way. I hope you know what I mean. So my question is: how do I make multiple actions that have different a duration on a single armature